# how do I decide angle while regressing values corresponding to a rotated rectangle?

Tags: geometry, deep-learning, regression

I am unable to interpret it. This is the paragraph (last two lines are important for my problem).

The simplest model we explore is a direct regression from
the raw RGB-D image to grasp coordinates. The raw image is
given to the model which uses convolutional layers to extract
features from the image. The fully connected layers terminate
in an output layer with six output neurons corresponding to
the coordinates of a grasp. Four of the neurons correspond
to location and height. **Grasp angles are two-fold rotationally
symmetric so we parameterize by using the two additional
coordinates: the sine and cosine of twice the angle.**

what does the bold line means?

More elaborate,

First, why twice the angle?

Second: what is two-fold rotationally symmetric?

Third: why can't I just regress angle directly?

This paragraph is from this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.3128.pdf) - page 2, right col, section B.

Comment: Would you please add a reference to the paragraph that you quote in your question?

Comment: @JamesPhillips - done.

Answer (score 0):

Second question is answered here: http://mathstat.slu.edu/escher/index.php/Rotational_Symmetry and as I understand it, this means that within a 360 degree circle the object can be rotated twice and visually appear the same.  As the subject of the paper is robotic vision, a grasp rectangle rotated by 45 degrees appears the same as a rectangle rotated by (180 + 45) degrees.

First and third questions: It appears that the neural network referenced in the paper could have used the angle directly as an input.  Due to the rotational symmetry the robotic vision could only resolve 180 degrees of rotation for the grasp rectangles, and to increase the sine and cosine outputs to a full 360 degrees for the neural network's neuron input range the detected visual rotation angle was doubled as a form of data conditioning.